# Non-option arguments with Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I'm trying to run an application on Spring Cloud Data Flow that requires a non-option argument (e.g. the command would be `java -jar task.jar non-option-argument --optionArgument=option` etc.)

The dashboard validation seems to prevent this from being done, as it requires all arguments to be in `key=value` combinations. Is it just unsupported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently that's the validation we have at the dashboard. But, I see your requirement and believe this can be fixed. Would you mind creating an issue [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow).

Also, the task launch page is getting revamped in 2.8.x (which is due for the release early next month) and we can possibly improve there as well.

Comment: Posted an issue. Glad to hear it's on the roadmap.